# Problems in building openjdk9 with the "make" command

Tags: java

os: mac os 10.13.6

I download all the source code of the openJDK9, and I read the README about it. I did what it told me to build the openJDK9.

The command below is how I configure the building process.

```
bash ./configure --with-target-bits=64 --with-freetype=/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.9 --enable-ccache --with-jvm-variants=server,client --with-boot-jdk-jvmargs="-Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked" --disable-zip-debug-info --disable-warnings-as-errors --with-debug-level=slowdebug 2>&1 | tee configure_mac_x64.log
```

And then, I typed a "make" command, and it worked well in a short time until the errors came. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK9Xa.png)

And the follow is the detail log for it

```
Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 1.133 Thread 0x00007fe60e004800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x00000007a01b3d20}: java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$Holder.identity_L(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;> (0x00000007a01b3d20) thrown at [../src/share/vm/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp, line 731]
Event: 1.139 Thread 0x00007fe60e004800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x00000007a01b6180}: java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$Holder.zero_L(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;> (0x00000007a01b6180) thrown at [../src/share/vm/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp, line 731]
Event: 1.141 Thread 0x00007fe60e004800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x00000007a01bae60}: java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeSpecial(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;> (0x00000007a01bae60) thrown at [../src/share/vm/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp,
Event: 1.163 Thread 0x00007fe60e004800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x00000007a01cf170}: java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeInterface(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)I> (0x00000007a01cf170) thrown at [../src/share/vm/interpreter/linkResolver.c
Event: 3.209 Thread 0x00007fe60e004800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x00000007a011c9f0}: java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeInterface(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;> (0x00000007a011c9f0) thrown at [../src/share/vm/interpreter/linkResolver.cp
Event: 3.322 Thread 0x00007fe60e004800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x00000007a01c61c8}: java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeStatic(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V> (0x00000007a01c61c8) thrown at [../src/share/vm/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp,
Event: 3.330 Thread 0x00007fe60e004800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x00000007a01cc7e0}: method resolution failed> (0x00000007a01cc7e0) thrown at [../src/share/vm/prims/methodHandles.cpp, line 1256]
Event: 3.351 Thread 0x00007fe60e004800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x00000007a01ed340}: java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeStatic(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)I> (0x00000007a01ed340) thrown at [../src/share/vm/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp, line 731]
Event: 3.355 Thread 0x00007fe60e004800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x00000007a01f2bb8}: method resolution failed> (0x00000007a01f2bb8) thrown at [../src/share/vm/prims/methodHandles.cpp, line 1256]
Event: 3.359 Thread 0x00007fe60e004800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x00000007a01f9e28}: java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeSpecial(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;> (0x00000007a01f9e28) th
```

My problem is that I don't know what "NoSuchMethodError" actually mean??
I copy the code in linkResolver.cpp at line 371 where I get the info from above, and there they are:

```
    // 5. method lookup failed
  if (resolved_method.is_null()) {
    ResourceMark rm(THREAD);
    THROW_MSG_CAUSE_(vmSymbols::java_lang_NoSuchMethodError(),
                    Method::name_and_sig_as_C_string(resolved_klass(),
                                                     link_info.name(),
                                                     link_info.signature()),
                    nested_exception, NULL);
  }
```

I am a new guy of openJDK, and that is very difficult for me to figure out those problems. I sucked here for a long time. Help! thx!

Comment: Nothing find. I used to build successful in my mac os 10.13.3, now I am in 10.13.6, and I failed with building it, and I don't know why?